# Optional Parameter in Routing works depending on parameter location

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a situation which I cannot solve easily.

```
Route::get( '{username?}/pet/add/', 'animalController@step2')->name('create-new-pet');
```

if the user does not have a username, a 404 error is thrown back, however when I move the parameter to the end like so:

```
Route::get( '/pet/add/{username?}', 'animalController@step2')->name('create-new-pet');
```

It works perfectly.

How can I make it so that the url would be `{username?}/pet/add`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you probably shouldn't have an optional segment and then have required segments after it ... doesn't make sense in how segments work. routes are URI structures and they are based on segments, if you remove a segment you have a completely different URI

Comment: The idea is that, if a group posts the url would be .../username/pet/add however if a user posts the content it'll just default to .../pet/add

Comment: which would be a completely different URI, its based on the segments ... this URI now only has 2 segments so it doesn't match the 3 segment URI you defined